# Need help fixing this coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am trying to make this script work in my `events.js.coffee`

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar(
    events: '/events.json'
              header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        }

  )
```

And, when i go to the rails page where that script is called i get an error that states:

> SyntaxError: [stdin]:8:24: unmatched OUTDENT.

How should I fix that code?

Comment: I think by adding `,` at the end of `events` key's value.

Comment: Added the , still get the same error . Thanks though !

Comment: not sure with given/available code but might be `'prev,next today'` to `'prev,next,today'`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies,

I managed to fix it by modifying the code as follows:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar(
           header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,agendaDay'
        },
           events: '/events.json'

  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
    events: 
    {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    header: 
    {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },
    events: '/events.json'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

CoffeeScript uses indentation to define the structure of your code so you **must** be very careful and consistent with your indentation: if you're using two spaces per level then always use two spaces per level everywhere. For example:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar(
    events: '/events.json'
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    }
  )
```

Or if you want to leave out the optional parentheses and braces:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar
    events: '/events.json'
    header:
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
```

Note the consistency in the indentation: each block is indented exactly two spaces more than its parent. You don't have to use two of course, you just need to be consistent or you'll end up with a big confusing mess on your hands.